# How can I pass an array to shared library(.dll) written in c using python

Tags: python, c, arrays, dll, ctypes

the function code of test.dll file:

```
double __cdecl add(int len,double array[]){}
```

(and I have tested it in vc)

python code:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import *

N=...
arr=(c_double*N)()
...
...
dll=CDLL("test.dll")
sum=dll.add(c_int(N),byref(arr))

print sum
```

but the python code doesn't work,
and the "sum"is always equal to N .(i.g. when N=10 ,it print"sum=10")
what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 9):

Passing an array in ctypes mirrors passing an array in C, i.e. you do not need to pass a reference to it as the array is already a reference to its first element.

```
from ctypes import *

N = ...
arr=(c_double*N)()
dll=CDLL("test.dll")
sum=dll.add(c_int(N),arr)

print sum
```

An example of this can be seen in the ctypes documentation under the [callbacks section](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions) when discussing interfacing with qsort.

Edit: As per David Heffernan's comment, you also require a `dll.add.restype = c_double` otherwise ctypes will assume the returned type is `c_int`.

Comment: You need `dll.add.restype=c_double` before you call the function. Otherwise ctypes assumes the return value is an int. Otherwise this is spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the function is defined as

```
double __cdecl add(int len, double array[]) { }
```

However, unless you specify the type of return value for it, ctypes defaults to `int`. This is analogous to declaring the function in C as

```
int __cdecl add(int len, double array[]);
```

Because the declaration and definition do not match, your code has *undefined behaviour*, i.e.:

> —  A function  is  defined  with  a  type  that  is  not  compatible  with  the  type  (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function (6.5.2.2).

---

In this specific case you're running on an architecture where the integer and floating point values are returned in registers; however `int` and `double` return values are stored in *different* registers. Now, the register that contains the return value of type `int` in this ABI happens to contain the `N` as a left-over. The correct return value was contained in a floating point register, however it wasn't ever used since ctypes expected to get an `int`.

Thus the correct fix is to do

```
dll.add.restype = c_double
```